# How to add library in android project?

Tags: android

when I want to add **this** library:

```
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
```

My android studio crashed this is my **app module**:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mahdi.introductionapps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

and this is my **error**:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing these things

`Clean & Rebuild Project`

Or

`File > Invalidate Caches and Restart > Invalidate and Restart`

Or

`Uncheck Gradle Work Offline`

Answer (score 1):

1. Try File->Invalidate Caches and Restart->Invalidate and Restart
2. If no luck try, File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build,
   Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Offline work and uncheck
   it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the library.

1. Go to Build > Clean Project.
2. then Build >Rebuild Project.
   and the library will be added normally.
   **Happy coding**